# is the natural numbers can be a valid subspace over some field?

Tags: linear-algebra

if i choose the real numbers as vector space over SOME field,
and i look on the subset of the natural numbers group including zero.
so according to subspaces:
1) 0 included 2) closed under addition of vectors.
so, is there a Field that can make the natural numbers as a valid subspaces? (field that multipication from natural numbers with scalar is closed) or it doesnt exist

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is that, since natural numbers form a monoid, one can talk about some monoid containing naturals as a submonoid; or the natural numbers can act by multiplication on some other monoid (the last written additively).

Answer (score 1):

The natural numbers, with the operation of addition, do not have a vector space structure over any field. To be a vector space, you first have to be a group, and most natural numbers do not have additive inverses.

The integers (again with addition) resolve this issue, since they include the negatives, but they still do not have a vector space structure over any field. The reason is that the integers are "non-torsion", i.e. $1+1+1+1+\dots$ never equals zero. Thus the field cannot have torsion either - it must be "[characteristic zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_%28algebra%29)." But [every characteristic zero field contains the rational numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_%28algebra%29#prime_field), and there will be no way to define multiplication of the integers by rational numbers since, e.g. there is no integer $x$ such that $5\cdot x = 2$, so there will be no good definition for $(1/5)\cdot 2$.

Comment: It looks like the OP asked about the natural numbers, not the integers.

Comment: @KevinCarlson - good point; I will edit. I was thrown by the word "group."